# android application save state

Tags: android, save

I am having trouble while developing Android application.

i declare custom search critiera object into application context, from every activity i want to access search critiera object from application context and then want to change Search critiera object.

oncrate() method i get searchcritiera and onresume i save this object into application context's search criteria.

ON an activity i have detect gps button when user click on the button it detect and store location object into search critiera.

- There are two problems, how can retain the search critiera object along the application cycle while every activity wants to change search critiera values ?
- when i move around and any other application comes front of my activity search critiera gets null from application context ....

help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any activity whenever the search criteria is changed to another value you can save it in SharedPreferences. 
    If you want to save the old value you can put it in a vector, then put it in SharedPreferences else just put the new value to ShraedPreferences.

In case of onResume() fetch the value with its tag name from SharedPreferences.